# Git branch directly from origin / master?

Tags: git, gerrit

I don't keep a local copy of origin/master. Keeps me from screwing it up. That being the case, how can I create a new local branch directly from remote origin / master?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a branch to checkout from when using the `-b` option as shown in the [git checkout documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout);

```
git checkout -b master_copy origin/master
```

This will create a branch called `master_copy` based on the current head of `origin/master`.

Comment: This looks like what I'm looking for! :-)

Comment: @user447607 can you please accept one of these answers? Thanks!

Comment: @user447607 you should accept Jarred Olson's answer.

Comment: I made it into an alias. ;-)
brr = "!f() { git checkout -B $1 origin/develop; };f"

This way I can go 'git brr MY_NEW_BRANCH'.